LaTeX3: detecting default command inputs once stored in sequences
I don't understand how to identify elements in a sequence that have a default value assigned by a document command.
For example,
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_blair_person_seq
\seq_new:N \l_blair_role_seq

\str_const:Nn \c_blair_NoValue_str {-NoValue-}

\NewDocumentCommand \AddPerson { m o }
{
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_blair_person_seq { #1 }
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_blair_role_seq { #2 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \PrintPeople {}
{
    
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \seq_count:N \l_blair_person_seq } 
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \l_tmpa_int }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_blair_person_seq {##1} }
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_blair_role_seq {##1} }
    
    \str_if_eq:NNTF \l_tmpb_tl \c_blair_NoValue_str 
    {True~(\l_tmpb_tl) \par}
    {False~(\l_tmpb_tl) \par}
   }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\AddPerson{Alice in Wonderland}[Hero]
\AddPerson{Bob}
\AddPerson{Charles}
\PrintPeople

\end{document}

I expected Alice to be detected because of the optional argument but she isn't. The output is
False (Hero)
False (-NoValue-)
False (-NoValue-)

Now, I tried to understand this with another little command
\NewDocumentCommand \AddSomething { m o }
{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
  \str_if_eq:NNTF \l_tmpa_tl \c_blair_NoValue_str 
   {Empty:~(\l_tmpa_tl)\par}
   {Full:~(\l_tmpa_tl)\par}
}

And in that case \AddSomething{once} is treated differently from \AddSomething{twice}[option]. So, I'm confused. What is wrong with my use of \str_if_eq:NNTF in the \PrintPeople command?
I'd also be grateful for some tips on how I might have debugged this.
EDIT:
It seems that replacing the lines
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_blair_person_seq {##1} }
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_blair_role_seq {##1} }

with stack pop instructions
    \seq_pop:NN \l_blair_person_seq \l_tmpa_tl
    \seq_pop:NN \l_blair_role_seq \l_tmpb_tl

allows my code to detect the default values. The output is then
False (Hero)
True (-NoValue-)
True (-NoValue-)

Can someone explain why my first attempt doesn't work?

etoolbox is mostly superseded by expl3. \str_set:Nn \c_NoValue_str should be \str_const:Nn \c_blair_NoValue_str -- you need the module name. \AddPerson should not be adding the no value marker to the sequence. \PrintPeople will produce an error if used again because you can't define an integer if it is already defined. You should never use seq as a module name because it is already taken by the l3kernel.

OK, thanks, but that's not the main point. Why is the default value not detected in \PrintPeople?

There are two issues with your approach. (Also, \str_const:Nn \c_blair_NoValue_str is missing a value - but I assume you have that in your real file.)
First,  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_blair_person_seq {##1} } sets the token list to _exactly) \seq_item:Nn \l_blair_person_seq { <whatever-#1-is> }, not to the result of expanding \seq_item:Nn here. So you are always comparing two things that will be different:

\seq_item:Nn \l_blair_person_seq { <whatever-#1-is> }
<content-of-c_blair_NoValue_str>

Even if you correct that, you test is likely to be defective as you are using a string comparison, but the code implies you are testing for -NoValue-. This is a 'special' token list that is not simply the string -NoValue-, so you have to test using \tl_if_novalue:nTF or similar.
When you pop from the sequence, you are setting \l_tmpa_tl to the extracted value, which then is what you want to compare. However, you can get the value by using expansion. I'd not bother with assignments at all normally, something like
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_novalue:nTF { e }
\NewDocumentCommand \PrintPeople {}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nn { \seq_count:N \l_blair_person_seq }
      {
        \seq_item:Nn \l_blair_person_seq {##1}
        \c_space_tl
        \tl_if_novalue:eTF { \seq_item:Nn \l_blair_role_seq {##1} }
          { ( FALSE ) }
          { ( \seq_item:Nn \l_blair_role_seq {##1} ) }
        \par
      }
  }

(If the sequence is huge this might be an issue, but normally that would not be the case.)

Drop \int_step_inline:nn and use \seq_map_pairwise_function:NNN instead.

@Skillmon Works for the demo but not if there are really more data structures or if we need the index for other reasons

Agreed. So we leave my comments such that one can find the alternative :)

When I was trying to understand this, I also tried with an optional command specified by O{}. Again, I had no success with my iteration (as has now been explained) but the stack-based approach allowed me to detect the chosen . @joseph, could your suggested method be changed easily to detect  instead of NoValue?

This might be a case for \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn

I now notice that replacing \tl_set:Nn with \tl_set:Nx inside the \int_step_inline block seems to make my code work.

@Blair That's full expansion, so yes: nowadays we'd favour \tl_set:Ne over \tl_set:Nx
